# jQuery add class to last tbody in a loop after each thead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html I have my markup is like this

```
<table class="section-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add a class for each last tbody after thead. So basically my output should be like this

```
<table class="section-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="last-row">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="last-row">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="last-row">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried this code but its not working at all.

```
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).nextAll('tbody').last().addClass('last-row');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that class to all `tbody` before `thead` and then add same class to last `tbody`

```
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prev('tbody').addClass('last-row');
});

jQuery('table.section-table').find('tbody').last().addClass('last-row');
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prev('tbody').addClass('last-row');
});

jQuery('table.section-table').find('tbody').last().addClass('last-row');
```

```css
.last-row
{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="section-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>12</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>312</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>rftg</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>g</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>345</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prev('tbody').addClass('last-row');
  });
  
  $('table.section-table tbody:last-child').addClass('last-row');
```

```css
.section-table tbody{
background-color:#F00;
}

.section-table tbody.last-row{
background-color:#FF0;
}


.section-table td{
height:30px;
width:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="section-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try prev('tbody'), since you don't have thead at the end, you need to add tbody:last-child as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the class to all the `<tbody>` that is just a previous element of the `<thead>`. Using this will leave you with the last `<tbody>` unchanged in the HTML table so you should add one more line of JQuery that will add class to this remaining last `<tbody>`.

```js
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
   jQuery(this).prev('tbody').addClass('last-row');
});
  
$('table.section-table tbody').last().addClass('last-row');
```

```css
.last-row{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="section-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to target all siblings till `<THEAD>` is encountered then use `.last()` to get the desired element and add class.

```
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).nextUntil('thead').last().addClass('last-row');
});
```

```js
jQuery('table.section-table').find('thead').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).nextUntil('thead').last().addClass('last-row');
});
```

```css
.last-row {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="section-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>HEAD 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>312</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>HEAD 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>HEAD 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```